# grab_set prevents borderless window from being focused

Tags: python, tkinter

When the dialog pops up the user is unable to interact with the root window (by clicking on the "Open Dialog" button, for example), which is the expected behavior. However, if the user tries to interact with the `popup` window in any way, it loses focus and closes because of the binding to `<FocusOut>`:

```
def on_focus_out(e):
    self.popup.withdraw()
self.popup.bind('<FocusOut>', on_focus_out)
```

Something is stealing the focus from the borderless window. If either `grab_set()` or `overrideredirect(True)` lines are omitted, then interaction doesn't generate a `<FocusOut>` event. So it seems I can't limit events to the dialog *and* interact with the `popup` without losing focus at the same time. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Below follows a simpler version of the program that reproduces the same problem.

```
from Tkinter import *


class Dialog(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.button = Button(self.frame, text='Show')
        self.popup = Toplevel(self)
        self.popup.transient(self)
        self.popup.overrideredirect(True)
        self.popup.withdraw()
        self.popup.config(bg='red')

        self.entry.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill=X, anchor=N)

        def on_focus_out(e):
            self.popup.withdraw()
        self.popup.bind('<FocusOut>', on_focus_out)

        def popup():
            w = self.winfo_width()
            h = 100
            x = self.winfo_rootx()
            y = self.winfo_rooty() + self.frame.winfo_height()
            geometry = "{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}".format(w, h, x, y)
            self.popup.geometry(geometry)
            self.popup.deiconify()
            self.popup.focus_set()
        self.button.config(command=popup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    opendlg_bttn = Button(root, text='Open Dialog')
    opendlg_bttn.pack(fill='none', expand=True)

    def open_dialog():
        dialog = Dialog(root)
        dialog.transient(root)
        dialog.grab_set()
        dialog.wait_window()
    opendlg_bttn.config(command=open_dialog)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You need to concentrate on the "M" -- you don't need all that code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I updated the question, hope this is better.